# Thunderbird Google calendar tab acts as mobile browser

Tags: thunderbird

I am using Thunderbird with the add-on Google Calendar Tab to display a browser tab with Google calendar. It works fine in Thunderbird for windows, but in TB for Ubuntu the browser tab gives me the mobile browser version of Google calendar.

Any idea why this is or if there is a way to change the browser user agent from within TB?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be a bug on Google's end.

A workaround, [as described here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/google-calendar-tab/reviews/), is to go to `Tools -> Add-ons -> Extensions`, click `Preferences` for the Google Calendar Tab plug-in and activate `Google Apps for your domain` with the following URL:

`https://www.google.com/calendar/render`

Comment: Happy to hear! Please mark this as the answer if that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

To get a 7-day view go to `Tools / Extensions / Google calendar Tab / Preferences`

Then enter the following URL in the URL entry for 7  day view:

> https://calendar.google.com/calendar/render#main_7

or

> https://calendar.google.com/calendar/render#main_7%7Cmonth

for a month view